# WebStorm Windows PowerShell aliases don't work

Tags: windows, powershell, webstorm, alias

When I run script (`"example":"docker ps"`) via WebStorm run button, I get:

```text
'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

PowerShell script works in Windows 11 terminal.

My aliases for docker:

```
# powershell
function docker { wsl -- docker $args }
```

```
# cmd
@echo off
DOSKEY docker=wsl -- docker $*
```

[image]

How to resolve this problem? I'm using pnpm.

Comment: Just to spell it out: the `DOSKEY` definition won't work in PowerShell (except if you unload the `PSReadLine` module, which significantly diminishes the command-line editing experience). For your PowerShell `function` to be available on startup, you must add it to a/your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) (and make sure that PowerShell isn't started with `-NoProfile`, which seems to be the case). As an aside: For robustness I suggest defining the function as `function docker { wsl -e docker $args }`